# Unexpected behaviour of \only

Tags: tikz-pgf, beamer

I don't understad why the following does not work.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \node (b) at (0,3) {b};
    \node (a) at (0,0) {a}
      \only<1>{edge[<-] node[auto] {c} (b)}    % doesn't work!
      % edge[<-] node[auto] {c} (b)
      ;
    \node<2> (d) at (5,0) {d};
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

I thought `\only` was supposed to use the content in selected frames and
throw it away otherwise.  Here inserting the content directly and
not works fine, but not with `\only`!  What am I missing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`overlays` and `tikz` are not fully compatible. By using the `overlay-beamer-styles` library, a few more possibilities are added. Then you could use the following code to show the arrow only on the first slide:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}

\usetikzlibrary{overlay-beamer-styles}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \node (b) at (0,3) {b};
    \node (a) at (0,0) {a}
       edge[<-,draw on=<1>] node[auto] {c} (b)
      ;
    \node<2> (d) at (5,0) {d};
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you!  Could I ask you to explain why what I did didn't work?

Comment: @Toothrot Tikz just does not support all of beamers overlay features.